# Is the sum of transcendental and algebraic number transcendental number?

Tags: analysis, transcendental-numbers

I know almost nothing about transcendental numbers, I know the definition of them and maybe few results about them and that is all.

But the question in the title somehow naturally arises when thinking about transcendental numbers.

I think that it is okay to state it once more in the body of the question and not only in the title so here is the question again:

> Suppose that $\alpha$ is some transcendental number and that $\beta$ is algebraic number. Is the sum $\alpha + \beta$ always transcendental?

Comment: Yes, as the set $\mathbf A := \{x \in \mathbf C: \text{$x$ is algebraic}\}$ is a subfield of $\mathbf C$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If α + β were algebraic, α = (α + β) – β would be algebraic, since algebraic numbers are a field.